# UX testing for multiple product mixes

Tags: testing, multiple-products

I am charged with testing a product mix change that takes what was **5 individual products and turns them into one product** that can be incremented to approximate the previous set of 5 products.

I am already conducting quantitative research through surveys around the existing & new product offering. My validation solution is to prototype the new singular product offering and conduct qualitative, in-person, moderated testing with the specific demographic of customers.

However, **I'm wondering if there are any other methods of validating the new product mix that one might recommend outside of this.**

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This being a "product mix" doesn't really change anything in terms of design process. I would suggest before you get into prototyping anything at all do some in-depth design & user research -maybe not just limit yourself to surveys. Which approach and techniques you want to use really just depends on what works best for you and is applicable to the type of product you have. Here is a good place to start. [Design Research Techniques](http://designresearchtechniques.com/#/)

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track, doing prototypes and getting surveys of customer feedback.

btw, have you used:

- Card sorting
- "Fly on the wall" or any other research where you observe the user doing actual tasks?